# Firefox shows strange markings in between navbar links

Tags: html, css, firefox, nightly-build

I am planning to use the Helios theme by HTML5up for a school project: http://html5up.net/helios/, but I noticed that Firefox (not Chrome, only Firefox) shows a cross inside of a box between navigation bar links, as shown here:

[image: Site navbar with error]

How can I change that? I must add I have Firefox Nightly and that I have noticed similar problems on other sites.

Answer (score 0):

That symbol is what results when Firefox fails a CORS request for a webfont. Can you check your network panel and confirm that all of the required webfonts are loading properly?

I'm not able to reproduce this in Firefox Nighly on Linux with v29.0a1 (2014-01-08).

Can you confirm that you don't have any extensions that may be conflicting with your pages?

Comment: Nor am I, same setup, adding Chrome 33 (as OP said) and Opera 12.16 as well

Comment: I'm also not able to reproduce this issue in Firefox 26 on Win 8.1.

Comment: What kind of extensions could cause that? I will try removing all of them in a moment. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: Well, everything seems to load properly and no extensions are conflicting with the page. I guess I'll just use FontSquirrel instead of googleFonts